# Converting a string to a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7, I want to convert a string in the following format to a list of lists:

```
>>> value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
>>> ...
>>> result = [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

I did manage to do just that, but it seems sloppy.

```
>>> value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
>>> val2 = value.replace('[[', '').replace(']]', '').split('] [')
>>> val2
['1 0 0 0', '0 1 0 0', '0 0 1 0', '0 0 0 1']
>>> val_final = [[float(x) for x in x] for x in [x.replace(' ', '') for x in val2]]
>>> val_final
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

**Is there a better, cleaner way to do this that would be more robust?**

Note: I do expect to only have integer or float values in the string (context: it's a 4x4 matrix corresponding to an object position in a 3D environment).

---

**Edit:**
Alternative value could contain floats like so:

```
>>> value = "[[9.231 -0.123 -2 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
>>> ...
>>> result = [[9.231, -0.123, -2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html#json.loads) from the standard library, with a little bit of preparation (replace spaces with commas) and asking it to convert all found integers as floats:

```
>>> import json
>>> value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
>>> result = json.loads(value.replace(' ', ','), parse_int=float)
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

That should be safer than eval and easier than manually parsing the string and convert it to the right datatypes, the json parser will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Johan Dahlin.
I did a comparison with `timeit`, and `eval` takes `0.2819679792258256`, while `json.loads` takes `0.038535186478554806`. 
Considering that I will have to convert thousands of values, this is the faster solution.

Comment: Your answer is just missing the conversion to float values.

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE I updated to to convert all numbers to float, but that might be a tiny bit slower when converting a larger dataset. For even better performance, switch the json library to something like https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson

Answer (score 4):

You can use `replace` + `eval`:

```
value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
result = eval(value.replace(" ", ","))
result
#output:
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

And to convert the integers to floats:

```
[list(map(float, l)) for l in result] #if you're using python 2 you can remove the "list" wrapping the "map" 
#output
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  People see eval and get scared, but this is a good solution IMO

Comment: This accomplishes exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamHughes They do have a reason to be scared... the last time I saw `eval` used, Martijn Pieters wrote a whole lot about why you should avoid it and alternatives but I lost that post.

Comment: You're welcome. @AdamHughes I also can't understand that

Comment: eval() isn't really safe, even if you replace space with comma, it's possible that malicious content can get execute code inside the string.

Comment: Yea, I guess the argument against `eval` is valid. It is also fairly slow. I did a comparison with `timeit`, and `eval` takes `0.2819679792258256`, while `json.loads` takes `0.038535186478554806`.

Comment: Well, I can see the downsides, but still don't think it's worth a downvote

Comment: @OhadEytan for sure (disclaimer: I did not downvote you, on the contrary)

Comment: `eval()` is a pretty bad idea specially when you have a much safer alternative in JSON

Answer (score 1):

Well the most flexible and extensible way would be to implement an [LL(1) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser). It requires a bit of work though.
Here is a rough implementation in Python 2.7:

```
value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"

class ParseError(ValueError):
    pass

def tokenize(s):
    buf = ""

    while s:
        if s[0] == '[':
            yield s[0]
        elif s[0].isalnum():
            buf += s[0]
        elif s[0] == ']':
            if buf:
                yield buf
                buf = ""
            yield ']'
        elif s[0] == ' ':
            if buf:
                yield buf
                buf = ""
        else:
            raise ParseError()
        s = s[1:]

def parse_array(tokens):
    if tokens[0] != '[':
        raise ParseError()
    tokens = tokens[1:]
    elements = []
    while tokens[0] != ']':
        element, tokens = parse(tokens)
        elements.append(element)

        if not tokens:
            raise ParseError()
    return elements, tokens[1:]

def parse_number(tokens):
    return float(tokens[0]), tokens[1:]

def parse(tokens):
    if tokens[0] == '[':
        return parse_array(tokens)
    elif tokens[0].isalnum():
        return parse_number(tokens)
    else:
        raise ParseError()

tokens = list(tokenize(value))
print tokens
# ['[', '[', '1', '0', '0', '0', ']', '[', '0', '1', '0', '0', ']', '[', '0', '0', '1', '0', ']', '[', '0', '0', '0', '1', ']', ']']
parsed, tokens = parse(tokens)
print parsed
# [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Note : haven't tested all the edge cases, but it should give an idea of how it may look like.

Here I'm assuming that:

- there can be any number of spaces between the numbers or brackets
- brackets don't need to be followed by a space
- the format represents [jagged arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array) (they can have rows of different lengths) of any dimensions (they can be arbitrarily nested).

This is pretty much the most permissive assumptions I can make about this format, so it's probably overkill if you don't need to handle these use cases. But if this is what you need, then congratulations, you have an LL(1) grammar (in other words, a small language), and you need this kind of solution.

There are two steps:

1. Tokenization: transforms a string to a sequence of symbols (brackets, number, and potentially other things like identifiers).
2. Parsing: transforms the sequence of symbols in an expression tree. To do that you need to read one symbol ahead before knowing how to interpret the following symbols (thus the 1 in LL1).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the Johan Dahlin's answer:

Instead of using *json* parser, you can user the integrated Python [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) parser:

Like this:

```
value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"

import ast

matrix = ast.literal_eval(value.replace(" ", ", "))
print(matrix)
# -> [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

With floats values:

```
# -> [[9.231, -0.123, -2, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

To "force" conversion to **float**, just write:

```
matrix = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in matrix]
print(matrix)
# -> [[9.231, -0.123, -2.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = "[[1 0 0 0] [0 1 0 0] [0 0 1 0] [0 0 0 1]]"
eval(value.replace(" ", ","))
```

Output :

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

for return float values

```
import numpy as np
l=np.array(eval(value.replace(" ", ",")))+0.
l.tolist()
```

Output

```
[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]
```